# Custom Cell in TableView hide label on DidSelect

Tags: swift, uikit, tableview, custom-cell

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I have a custom cell which has its own `UITableViewCell` and nib (3 labels).

If I select the cell I want to show/hide the Resolved Label.  I can't seem to change the ResolvedLabel to Hidden or Show.  The function gets called as I can see the Print Statement.

Code in `didSelectRowAt`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! ResolvedIssueTableViewCell


    if cell.resolvedLabel.isHidden == true {

        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        print("THIS HAS BEEN SELECTED RESOLVED")

        cell.resolvedLabel.isHidden = false

        self.resolvedIssueType.append(self.issues[indexPath.row].partType)
        self.resolvedIssues.append(self.issues[indexPath.row].documentId)
        print(self.resolvedIssues)

    } else if cell.resolvedLabel.isHidden == false {

        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        print("THIS HAS BEEN SELECTED NOT RESOLVED")
        cell.resolvedLabel.isHidden = true

        if let index = self.resolvedIssues.firstIndex(of:self.issues[indexPath.row].documentId) {
            self.resolvedIssues.remove(at: index)
            self.resolvedIssueType.remove(at: index)
        }
        print(self.resolvedIssues)
        print(self.resolvedIssueType)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call `tableView.reloadData()` in the end of `didSelectRowAt` function.

*I've done some refactor your code*

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? ResolvedIssueTableViewCell else { return }

    if cell.resolvedLabel.isHidden {

        print("THIS HAS BEEN SELECTED RESOLVED")
        cell.resolvedLabel.isHidden = false

        self.resolvedIssueType.append(self.issues[indexPath.row].partType)
        self.resolvedIssues.append(self.issues[indexPath.row].documentId)
        print(self.resolvedIssues)

    } else {

        print("THIS HAS BEEN SELECTED NOT RESOLVED")
        cell.resolvedLabel.isHidden = true

        if let index = self.resolvedIssues.firstIndex(of:self.issues[indexPath.row].documentId) {
            self.resolvedIssues.remove(at: index)
            self.resolvedIssueType.remove(at: index)
        }
        print(self.resolvedIssues)
        print(self.resolvedIssueType)

    }

    tableView.reloadData() // Here is the magic :)
}
```

**You can learn more from [Nicholas Swift's Medium Article](https://medium.com/ios-seminar/why-we-use-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier-ce7fd97cde8e)**

Comment: Reloading the tableView wasn't able to update the hidden property of the label

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, it doesn't matter why this doesn't work because the whole approach should be different.

Instead of directly trying to manipulate the cell, something that can be problematic for a *lot* of reasons (the main one being cell reusability), change the model (as you already do) and refresh the tableView - or better yet refresh just the affected cell.

So your code would be something like this (please note that I have no way to test this, so it's from the top of my head, but the genera idea is valid):

**1.** Make the change in the model

**2.** Reflect that change in your view (the cell)

---

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? ResolvedIssueTableViewCell else {
        print("Wrong type of cell. Bailing out...")
        return
    }

    let isResolved = ...// Probably by looking into something like `self.resolvedIssues.firstIndex(of:self.issues[indexPath.row].documentId)` judging from your code

    if isResolved {
        print("THIS HAS BEEN SELECTED RESOLVED")
        self.resolvedIssueType.append(self.issues[indexPath.row].partType)
        self.resolvedIssues.append(self.issues[indexPath.row].documentId)
        print(self.resolvedIssues)
    } else {
        print("THIS HAS BEEN SELECTED NOT RESOLVED")
        if let index = self.resolvedIssues.firstIndex(of:self.issues[indexPath.row].documentId) {
            self.resolvedIssues.remove(at: index)
            self.resolvedIssueType.remove(at: index)
        }
        print(self.resolvedIssues)
        print(self.resolvedIssueType)

    }

    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
}
```

then make the visual state of your cells reflect your model:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = ...
    cell.resolvedLabel.isHidden = <whatever_makes_sense>
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After select row. call tableview.reloaddata() function.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! ResolvedIssueTableViewCell


    if cell.resolvedLabel.isHidden == true {

        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        print("THIS HAS BEEN SELECTED RESOLVED")

        cell.resolvedLabel.isHidden = false

        self.resolvedIssueType.append(self.issues[indexPath.row].partType)
        self.resolvedIssues.append(self.issues[indexPath.row].documentId)
        print(self.resolvedIssues)

    } else if cell.resolvedLabel.isHidden == false {

        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        print("THIS HAS BEEN SELECTED NOT RESOLVED")
        cell.resolvedLabel.isHidden = true

        if let index = self.resolvedIssues.firstIndex(of:self.issues[indexPath.row].documentId) {
            self.resolvedIssues.remove(at: index)
            self.resolvedIssueType.remove(at: index)
        }
        print(self.resolvedIssues)
        print(self.resolvedIssueType)

    }

   tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Reloading wasn't able to show/hide the label.
Its either shown or not shown and then won't update,

Answer (score 0):

As always, **keep all information about one row in the data model** rather than using separate arrays. In `didSelectRowAt` modify the model and reload the row. This is the most reliable and efficient way.

---

In the data model add a property

```
var isResolved = false
```

in `cellForRow` set the `hidden` property of the text field depending on `isResolved`.

```
let issue = self.issues[indexPath.row]
cell.resolvedLabel.isHidden = issue.isResolved
```

Replace `didSelectRowAt` with (yes, the 3 lines are sufficient)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    self.issues[indexPath.row].isResolved.toggle()
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
}
```

and delete the two extra arrays.

---

To get all resolved items just `filter` the array

```
let resolvedIssues = self.issues.filter{ $0.isResolved }
```